# Is it possible to have own custom Context Menu in ag-Grid-community

Tags: ag-grid

Can't find the exact answer.
If i decide to opt-in for vanilla JavaScript (non-Angular & Co) ag-Grid-community edition, can i have easy to add my own custom context menu an other custom extensions?
As i seen their docs, context menu is only enterprise level feature.
I seen some treads that there is some caveats, but i personally did not dig deeper.
In general, how easy is to implement self-built features in ag-Grid-community. Or it is better to write own grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a custom context menu component in our Angular project with ag-grid community, so it's definitely possible.

**How it works:**

We define all grid columns in templates. If you want a context menu, you put an empty column into the column set and put a special directive on it. The directive accepts a context menu template, which is passed into a custom `cellRendererFramework` (a menu trigger button, basically). The directive also configures the column to ensure consistent look across grid instances.

This might be not what you've been looking for if you require for menu to open with right mouse click anywhere in a row, but I suppose it shouldn't be *that* hard to trigger the menu from a different event (check out ag-grid events, there might something suitable).

The snippets below should be straightforward to adapt for your framework of choice. Given you opted into vanilla JS, you'll have to use regular functions to do the same, something like this:

`const grid = withContextMenu(new Grid(element, gridOptions), menuOptions)`.

Here's an example of how we use it:

```
<ag-grid-angular>
  <ag-grid-column headerName='ID' field='id'></ag-grid-column>
  <ag-grid-column [contextMenu]='menu'>
    <mat-menu #menu='matMenu'>
      <ng-template matMenuContent let-item='data'>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)='restoreSnapshot(item.id)'>Restore From Snapshot</button>
        <a mat-menu-item [routerLink]='[item.id, "remove"]'>Remove</a>
      </ng-template>
    </mat-menu>
  </ag-grid-column>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

The directive that applies the menu:

```
const WIDTH = 42;
export const CONTEXT_MENU_COLID = 'context-menu';

@Directive({
  selector: '[agGridContextMenu]'
})
export class AgGridContextMenuDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private gridComponent: AgGridAngular) {}

  @Input()
  agGridContextMenu!: ElementRef<MatMenu>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (!this.agGridContextMenu) return;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.gridComponent.api.setColumnDefs([
        ...this.gridComponent.columnDefs,
        {
          colId: CONTEXT_MENU_COLID,
          cellRendererFramework: CellRendererContextMenuComponent,
          width: WIDTH,
          maxWidth: WIDTH,
          minWidth: WIDTH,
          cellStyle: {padding: 0},
          pinned: 'right',
          resizable: false,
          cellRendererParams: {
            suppressHide: true,
            contextMenu: {
              menu: this.agGridContextMenu
            }
          }
        }
      ]);
    });
  }
}
```

The cell renderer component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cell-renderer-context-menu',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf='params.data && params.colDef.cellRendererParams.contextMenu.menu'>
      <button
        type='button'
        mat-icon-button
        [matMenuTriggerFor]='params.colDef.cellRendererParams.contextMenu.menu'
        [matMenuTriggerData]='{data: params.data}'
      >
        <mat-icon svgIcon='fas:ellipsis-v'></mat-icon>
      </button>
    </ng-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./cell-renderer-context-menu.component.scss']
})
export class CellRendererContextMenuComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  params!: ICellRendererParams;
  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams) {
    this.params = params;
  }
  refresh() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

A screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I followed this blogpost, using community edition ag-grid, and it worked! I was surprised because previously I had the experience that cell renderers didn't allow content outside of the cell boundaries to be shown, but somehow popper/tippy is getting around that (I think it adds itself to the top of the DOM with this section of code `appendTo: document.body`).

https://blog.ag-grid.com/creating-popups-in-ag-grid/

basically, in my javascript `CellRenderer`:

```
class MyCellRenderer{
  // https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/
  init(e){
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.container = document.createElement("span");
    let menubutton = document.createElement("button");
    menubutton.innerHTML="&#x1F80B"; //downward arrow
    this.tippyInstance = tippy(menubutton);
    this.tippyInstance.disable();
    this.container.appendChild(menubutton);
    menubutton.addEventListener('click', that.togglePopup.bind(this));
  }

  getGui() {
    return this.container;
  }

  togglePopup() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
      if (this.isOpen) {
        this.configureTippyInstance();
        this.eMenu = this.createMenuComponent();
        this.tippyInstance.setContent(this.eMenu);
      } else {
        this.tippyInstance.unmount();
      }
  }

  configureTippyInstance() {
    this.tippyInstance.enable();
    this.tippyInstance.show();
    this.tippyInstance.setProps({
      trigger: 'manual',
      placement: 'bottom-start',
      arrow: false,
      interactive: true,
      appendTo: document.body,
      hideOnClick: true,
      onShow: (instance) => {
        tippy.hideAll({ exclude: instance });
      },
      onClickOutside: (instance, event) => {
        this.isOpen = false;
        instance.unmount();
      },
    });
  }

  createMenuComponent() {
    let menu = document.createElement('div');
    menu.classList.add('menu-container');
    let options = {};
    options['Delete Row'] = this.menuItemClickHandler.bind(this);
    options['Popup an Alert!'] = function(){alert("hello!");};
    options['Popup an Alert 2!'] = this.menuItemClickHandler.bind(this);

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(options)) {
      let item = document.createElement('div');
      item.classList.add('menu-item');
      item.setAttribute('data-action', key.toLowerCase());
      item.classList.add('hover_changes_color');
      item.innerText = `${key}`; // string formatting example
      item.addEventListener('click', value);
      menu.appendChild(item);
    }
    return menu;
  }

  menuItemClickHandler(event) {
    this.togglePopup();
    const action = event.target.dataset.action;
    if (action === 'delete row') {
        this.params.api.applyTransaction({ remove: [this.params.data] });
    }
    if (action === 'popup an alert 2!') {
      alert("2");
    }
  }
}
```

and in `styles.css`:

```
.hover_changes_color:hover {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```